# How to call a factory from a service in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an AngularJS app I setup using Yeoman. In the app, I need to make an API call that is behind `HTTP Basic Authentication`. I followed [this tutorial](http://wemadeyoulook.at/en/blog/implementing-basic-http-authentication-http-requests-angular/) to figure out how to modify my HTTP headers and encode the uername and password. However, I cannot figure out how to call `Base64.encode` from my API service. Everything I've tried keeps giving me `ReferenceError: Base64 is not defined` errors.

My API Service, `Base64.encode()` is the line that throws the error:

```
// app/scripts/api.js
angular.module('api.ClientApp', ['base64']).
    service('$api', function($http, $q, $cookieStore, $rootScope, $location, $window, $sniffer) {
        var $api = this;

        this.set_http_auth = function(obj) {
            if(obj){
                $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' +
                    Base64.encode(obj.username + ':' + obj.password);
            } else {
                delete $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'];
            }
        };
    });
```

Base64 Factory:

```
// app/scripts/services/Base64.js
angular.module('base64', [])
    .factory('Base64', function () {
        return {
            encode: function (input) {
                var output = "";
                // ...
                return output;
            },

            decode: function (input) {
                var output = "";
                // ...
                return output;
            }
        };
    });
```

Index.html:

```
<!-- app/index.html -->
<script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/services/Base64.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/api.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/controllers/signin.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this line

```
service('$api', function($http, $q, $cookieStore, $rootScope, $location, $window, $sniffer) {
```

you need to inject the Base64 service - i.e.

```
service('$api', function($http, $q, $cookieStore, $rootScope, $location, $window, $sniffer, Base64) {
```

Comment: Thanks! I spent way too long on that for such a simple solution. I was so close!